# How to update ddrescue Macport version?

Tags: macports, ddrescue

I'm running ddrescue version 1.20, but the latest version is 1.21. I used MacPorts to install ddrescue, and according to their [ports page](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=category&substr=sysutils&page=2&pagesize=50) only 1.20 is available to download and install through the MacPorts Project. What I would like to know is, could I somehow update the ddrescue version to 1.21 via rebuilding/updating the port, or would I have to compile it myself, independently of MacPorts?

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of the port here. I updated the ddrescue port to version 1.21 now. Next time, you should rather file such requests as a ticket in the [MacPorts issue tracker](https://trac.macports.org/), where this would get more attention.